# VMware VM has internet adapters but no network connection

Tags: networking, windows-10, virtual-machine, vmware

[image]

I recently used the VM conversion center to migrate my physical PC to a VM. Now I'm running into a problem though. As you can see, I've got (multiple) network adapters. They all seem to work fine, "This device is working properly.", and the events log states the device was started properly. However, the network connections manager does not show me any network adapter. I've tried all 3 types of adapter. E1000 and E1000E, and the VMXNet3 (which currently shows as Unknown device, due to my messing about while trying to fix this problem.)

What could cause this problem, and how could I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

These kind of issues will be automatically fixed by installing the VMtools. Once it is installed, it will automatically show the available network adapters in network connections manager.
After that try to ping loop back ip and assign a valid ip for your VM machine.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, I've tried adding, removing and modifying VMware tools multiple times.